# How do I remove the black side bars from my video header youtube link in Wordpress Twenty-Seventeen?

Tags: wordpress, header, youtube-iframe-api

I used the twenty-seventeen customize tool to add an embedded youtube video to my header-media, by only providing a link url.

But it displays with 2 black side bars, on the left and right of the video. From reading other posts, this is how Youtube formatted the video to display. But is there a way to override this somehow?

My work-in-progress website is: [www.diatomfilms.com](http://www.diatomfilms.com) so you can see the problem.

Comment: Please provide the code where the problem is occurring so that we can better help.  Please read about Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and provide one.

Answer (score -1):

Found this article with quick google search: https://filmora.wondershare.com/youtube-video-editing/remove-youtube-videos-black-bars.html

I guess the fourth solution in the article would be helpful for you because you have already uploaded the video on YouTube.

> Click on the Edit button next to the video, and add the most suited
>   instruction in the Tag bar below:

[image]

> t:crop=16:9 This tag zooms in on the video because of which the
>   contents at the borders (black bars in this case) do not appear
>   anymore.
>
> yt:stretch=16:9 This tag stretches the video in the aspect ratio of
>   16:9. It is used to view the video in wide-screen format.
>
> yt:stretch=4:3 if your video is appearing in wide-screen format, but
>   you want it to display in 720 x 480 pixels, apply this tag. It scales
>   down the video 4:3 aspect.